# How to highlight 1st level menu item based on actual page

Tags: menus, pages, sub-menu, child-pages

I am trying to highlight 1st level menu item by adding 'current-menu-item' class using nav_menu_css_class filter based on actual page / article / post / etc.

For example, menu looks like this:

Publications -> Computers -> Article 123

So, once user enters "Article 123" page I would like to highlight "Publications" menu section. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, very much possible and you don't even have to add classes yourself. If you're using `wp_nav_menu`, Wordpress adds classes for every case the specific nav item is in. I'll name the important classes for Publications (amongst others), based on where you clicked hypothetically:

1. Publications - This is now the selected item, and will get (amongst others) the classes: `current-menu-item` because it's selected
2. Computers - Publications is not the selected item, but will get the classes: `current-page-parent` and `current-menu-parent` because it's direct child is the selected item, and `current-page-ancestor` and `current-menu-ancestor` because one of it's children down the line is the selected item
3. Article 123 - Publications is not the selected item, but will get the classes: `current-page-ancestor` and `current-menu-ancestor` because one of it's children down the line is the selected item

So in short, `current-menu-item` when selected, `[classname part]-parent` when direct child is selected and `[classname part]-ancestor` when child, grand-child or deeper level child is selected